# Positive Definite iff the determinant of all upper-left submatrices $> 0$ - Always true?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-decomposition

**Theorem.** A $M_{n \times n}$ matrix is positive (negative) definite iff the determinate of all upper-left sub matrices are positive (negative).

However, consider this matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 1 & 2 \\
        2 & 4 & 3 \\
        -1 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

If I am not mistaken I take the upper-left submatrices and their respective determinant to be

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\Longrightarrow 3$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 1 \\
        2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\Longrightarrow 10$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 1 & 2 \\
        2 & 4 & 3 \\
        -1 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\Longrightarrow 25$$

But this matrix isn't strictly positive definite of negative definite. It you find the eigenvalues (I'd suggest using some type of software - can also try to plug in for the Cholesky Decomposition and should given an error) you get eigenvalues with real and complex parts.

The real parts are all $> 0$, but the complex parts are not. Does this mean the matrix is positive definite in the reals, but not strictly positive definite?

Comment: Your matrix isn't symmetric

Comment: Yes, the result you quote is true of *symmetric* matrices, not general ones.

Comment: Is there no extension for matrices that are not symmetric?

Comment: @user334916 a non-symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite iff the symmetric matrix $A + A^T$ is positive definite.

Comment: Just found on the wiki page that "some authors choose to say that a complex matrix M is positive definite if Re(z*Mz) > 0 for all non-zero complex vectors z. This weaker definition encompasses some non-Hermitian complex matrices, including some non-symmetric real ones, such as ((1,1),(-1,1))"

Comment: @user334916 are you asking about real matrices, or are your potentially complex?

Comment: I assume real. By your definition above my matrix is positive definite then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was stated in comments, the [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) requires the matrix to be symmetric. A simpler example with a non-symmetric matrix would be 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
which makes it clear that none of the upper-left determinants are influenced by the entry $2$; thus they do not detect its effect on the signature of the matrix.

To determine positive-definiteness of a non-symmetric matrix one can apply Sylvester's criterion to $(A+A^T)/2$, which generates exactly the same quadratic form as $A$ itself.